# TextView ignores left and right margins

Tags: android, layout, textview

My layout includes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFindPOIs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Find POIs"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnGetLocation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPoiDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFindPOIs" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When the content of TextView extends beyond one line it correctly flows to a second line but the text extends right to the edge of the screen ignoring the 16dp left and right margins.

Answer (score 1):

Layout Margin affects the View object, in this case a TextView. Not the actual text inside the object. So it will still go right up against the object's edge.
I would recommend using padding, it will directly affect the text. You may also want to consider adding gravity to the object?

I would also recommend using layout weights on these views or you are going to have resizing issues!

```
android:paddingStart="16dp"
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. The padding works, but I don't understand why. As I understand, marginStart dictates how much space is allowed between the TextView and its parent (the screen), whereas padding dictates the space that is allowed inside the TextView between its edge and and its content. So why, with my original layout (implicit zero padding) does the text not stop at the edge of the TextView, 16dp from the edge of the screen?

Comment: Ah, that would most likely be caused by your width attribute. You have it set to wrap_content. This will ignore constraints and margins typically. Instead try setting it to match_constraint aka 0dp. Usually its best to either use match_constraint or match_parent on the width. You can always force space by using a Space and nesting two spaces + a text view inside of a horizontal linear layout, then using layout weights. Nested weights are considered bad practice, but you can do it.